# How to replace Budgie software manager, or repair it

Tags: package-management

Software manager has become slow to respond, particularly to show "installed". Can I replace the standard software manager with something else, or solve the slow problem. When I did "sudo apt update" terminal mentioned multiple instances, and it is true I do have three icons for "variety" as an example.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details (a starting point to understanding potential problems) & I don't understand your actual issue. We can't read the `sudo apt update` messages unless you provide them for us to see for example, and multiple issues there are errors added by users on your box with `sudo` rights; just fix them). Your seem to be talking about multiple issues though and it's just unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What do you mean by "Budgie software manager"? Could you please add a screenshot of it? Is it GNOME Software or Ubuntu Software application? Do you any errors on `sudo apt update` ?